# How to handle multiple file uploads in Django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I've been banging my head on how to handle multiple file uploads in drf ,
my vue.js front-end is sending the files but i don't know how to hanfle them in my back-end .

**views.py**

```
class FileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    parser_classes = (FormParser,MultiPartParser)
    queryset = File.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FileSerializer
```

**serializers.py**

```
    class FileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = File
        fields = ('id', 'file','uploaded_at')
```

**models.py**

```
class File(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files/')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def delete(self, *args, **kargs):
        self.file.delete()
        super().delete(*args, **kargs)
```

What is sent from my front-end :

[image]
Any idea?

Comment: are you able to select multiple file in frontend ?

Comment: Yes , it sends them correctly i belieave , i'll update the my question with form Data .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your serializer does not match the data frontend sends. FileSerializer expects to receive `{file: DjangoFile}` but what is really needed (and send by frontend) is `{files: [DjangoFile, DjangoFile]}`.
So, serializer should be:

```
class FilesSerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    files = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.FileField())
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        files = validated_data['files']
        file_objs = [File.objects.create(file=file) for file in files]
        return file_objs
```

You'll also probably receive an error when constructing the response, so add `read_only=True` to the `FilesSerializer.files`.